# HTML CSS hover button navigation

Tags: html, css

I am using an image button for navigation, because I want hover effects.
I mean, I used button image instead of `<ul>` tag or `<div>` tag because I want hover effects, meaning when I hover on that image the image changes. That's why I use image button.

But, I do not want to use images. I want to use `<ul>` tag and `<div>` tag but I am not familiar with how to do hover effect on those tags.

Please help me.

Comment: If you are going to down vote a new user, at least tell them why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use CSS to do this. If you wish to have a list of buttons, then I strongly suggest you use a ul parent element and then li child elements. Don't use divs inside the ul.

```
<ul>
    <li id='button1'>Button 1</li>
    <li id='button2'>Button 2</li>
</ul>

#button1 {background-image: url(IMAGE PATH GOES HERE)}
#button1:hover {background-image: url(HOVER IMAGE PATH GOES HERE)}
```

The CSS property [background-image](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_background.asp) places whatever image you specify in IMAGE PATH GOES HERE as the background for that element. The :hover pseudo-selector allows you to alter an image when the user hovers it with their mouse. In this case, we are providing a different image path effectively altering the image when the li is hovered.

In case you are not familiar with CSS, [you can learn more about it here](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_intro.asp).

Comment: Thanks for this answer but i do not want to use images...in that case how can i implement this code...

Comment: @giteshdang What effect are you trying to create on the hover? Essentially, you just need to change background-image to whatever property you are trying to alter. I can't tell you which one without knowing what effect you are trying to create. If you tell me the effect I will try and point you in the right direction.

Comment: actualy in some web sites when we hover the pointer on the navigation button there is a change on the background of button..i want to know that is that image or div..???

Comment: What is the button? Is it a button tag or a div tag? If it is a div tag then the image is being added to the button via CSS and then being changed using :hover, just as in my example. Post a link to an example.

Answer (score 1):

All modern browsers can render `:hover` CSS selector on every element. You just have to change `background-image` properties for your `<ul>` tags then.

But there are many possibilities with javascript, jquery and so on, which will enable you to use it in every browser.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand but if I do it's this:

```
ul:hover
{
background-color: #f00;
}
```

or

```
div:hover
{
background-color: #f00;
}
```

About as good an answer I can give considering the question.